# Mifare/Calypso Cards vs regular Tap and Go Smart Card Inteference

Tags: rfid, mifare

I've been using an RFID blocking material in a build. I've noticed that it will stop bank cards being read when i try to tap and Go through the material, but will not stop transit cards.

Both are 13.56 Mhz and seem to be based on ISO 14443, why is one able to penetrate the RFID blocking material but the other is not?

I tried tapping both cards with a layer of the blocker material between them and the transit card reader or payment terminal respectively.